# PySpark job fails in local with heap memory issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm facing the following exception when I run my PySpark jobs in local (laptop)

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.)
....
```

I have only few records in the data frame (< 10 rows); however, it works fine in the actual cluster with 100K records.

Another finding is; in local it takes **2 hours** before it fails but in cluster it finishes in 15 mns with 100K records. Indeed I have complex logic with multiple join/explodes but it is not giving me an idea why it fails for small record set. Any configurations will resolve it?

Comment: It might be helpful for others if you also share the configuration parameters you pass to spark-submit, such as driver and executor memory parameters. Also, depending on the actual join and explode steps, it might be trying to allocate a lot of temporary memory, leading to problems.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happens for a lot of reasons, you should look more into your logic. You can try to increase memory for Spark and see how does it react, by default it's 512M

This is an example for pyspark.

```py
sc = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "4g").getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Comment: Tried with increasing memory and caching but nothing helps.